# How to make Python tornado generate chunked response

Tags: python, tornado, httpresponse, chunked

My python version is 3.4, my tornado version is 4.3.My code is like this:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.httputil
import tornado.httpserver


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        body = 'foobar'*10
        self.set_header('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked')
        self.write(body)
        self.flush()
        self.finish()


app = tornado.web.Application([
        (r'/chunked', MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.listen(8080)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

This simply can not work, client just wait for the chunk ends.How to generate a chunked response properly when using tornado server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A single call to `write` will result in a single chunk in the response. To get multiple chunks you must call `write` several times, flush each time, and `yield` in between (if you're not yielding anything then there is no value in using chunks for the response).

```
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def get(self):
    for i in range(10):
        self.write('foobar')
        yield self.flush()
```

Comment: Also, do not set the Transfer-Encoding header by hand (unless you also generate all the chunked-encoding framing). That's for the server framework to control.